# Get Change in any Element

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I have a screen with a few components (textInput, textArea, checkBox). I want to check if there has been any changes to the components. Foe example if text has been entered or checkbox has been clicked.

Is there a direct way to do this instead of checking value of each component and then setting a Boolean for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three Spark components you listed (TextInput, TextArea, CheckBox) all listen for a change event. Simply call a function to be notified when change events occur on each component, like so:

```
<s/TextInput change="myTextInputChangeHandler(event)"/>
<s/TextArea change="myTextAreaChangeHandler(event)"/>
<s/CheckBox change="myCheckBoxChangeHandler(event)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create some class which contains data and tracks changes. And bind controls with this data object fields using two way binding.

The base class for you data object can look like the following:

```
public class DataObjectsBase extends EventDispatcher
{
    protected function setNewSetterValue(propertyName:String, value:Object):void
    {
        var internalPropertyName:String = "_" + propertyName;
        var oldValue:Object = this[internalPropertyName];
        if (oldValue == value)
            return;
        this[internalPropertyName] = value;
        dispatchUpdateEvent(propertyName, oldValue, value);
    }

    protected function dispatchUpdateEvent(propertyName:String, oldValue:Object, value:Object):void
    {
        makeChanges();
        dispatchEvent(PropertyChangeEvent.createUpdateEvent(this, propertyName, oldValue, value));
    }

    protected function makeChanges():void
    {
        if (!_changed)
        {
            _changed = true;
            dispatchEvent(new Event("changedChanged"));
        }
    }

    public function resetChanges():void
    {
        _changed = false;
        dispatchEvent(new Event("changedChanged"));
    }

    private var _changed:Boolean = false;

    [Bindable("changedChanged")]
    public function get changed():Boolean
    {
        return _changed;
    }
}
```

This implementation relies on naming convention of the following kind:

```
public class MyDataImplementation extends DataObjectsBase
{
    private var _comment:String = "";

    [Bindable(event = "propertyChange")]
    public function get comment():String
    {
        return _comment;
    }

    public function set comment(value:String):void
    {
        setNewSetterValue("comment", value);
    }
}
```

So private field should be named the same as accessor but starting with underscore.

If you fill your data class with several fields (strings, booleans etc) you can use it the following way:

```
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    [Bindable]
    private var personalInfo:PersonalInfo /* extends our DataObjectsBase */;
]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:TextInput text="@{personalInfo.firstName}" />
<s:CheckBox selected="@{personalInfo.receivePromotions}" />
<s:Button label="Apply" enabled="{personalInfo.changed}" />
```

This code is just a draft but I hope you get the idea :)

Comment: Thx sir..I am trying this as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You can register an event listener on each of the components to automatically listen for changes.

If you are trying to figure out if a change has occurred from a specific time (or last checked instance) the only way (I know) would be storing the previous input (hash of input) and comparing it to the current input (hash of the current input) .